# Getting unique ID after insert on DetailsView using EntityDataSource

Tags: c#-4.0, detailsview, entitydatasource

I am using C#, .net 4.0.  I have a DetailsView that I am using to insert values.  The DetailsView is databound to an EntityDataSource control using the DataSourceId property.

The EntityDataSource is connecting to a Sql Server 2008 database table called Issues (via the EDMX file).

I need to find the unique id from the newly inserted row after the insert has taken place.  The sql table uses a UniqueIdentifier data type and is the id column is called "IssueId".

I have tried this:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AffectedRows > 0)
    {
        int issueId = 0;
        int.TryParse(e.Values["IssueId"].ToString(), out issueId);
    }
}
```

However I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the line where I say "int.TryParse".

What I need to know is how do I get the unique ID from the item that has just been inserted?

Answer (score 3):

So, coming back to this four months later...

I don't think you can get the unique ID during the ItemInserted event on the DetailsView.  Instead you have to get it from the Inserted event on the EntityDataSource control.

Like so:

```
protected void edsIssues_Inserted(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs e)
{
        int issueId = 0;
        issueId = ((Model.Issue)e.Entity).IssueId;
}
```